# Hashi Consul installed - now getting daily errors and lots of logs

Tags: kubectl, consul

Not sure how to resolve this. Installed Consul as a test, I'm new to containers and service mesh in general, so I wanted to learn a bit. This is all installed on Windows. Every day at 9AM I get a pop up with the following:

[image]

This will go down the list of log files for HOURS. Checked the folder in question, has 1.7M files in it.. All of which are 0 to 1 KB in size. Nothing in them, but the timestamps show they get added everyday every minute or so.

I don't know what is kicking off this process and I don't know how these files are being added. Since I'm new to this, I'm not sure where to go. Checked Hashi for how to uninstall Consul but none of the commands are working.

Thoughts?